# How to remove RichTextBox's first, blank line?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a RichTextBox defined like this in .xaml file:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="logTextBox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="14"  Margin="48,10,49,9" Background="Black">
            <RichTextBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="500" />
                </Style>
            </RichTextBox.Resources>
        </RichTextBox>
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
    public void AddLog(string log, Color color)
    {
        Run run = new Run(log);
        run.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(run);
        var numberOfBlocks = logTextBox.Document.Blocks.Count;
        const int MaxNumberOfBlocks = 100;
        if(numberOfBlocks > MaxNumberOfBlocks)
        {
            logTextBox.Document.Blocks.Remove(logTextBox.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock);
        }
        logTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        logTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
    }
```

Overall, it looks nice and does everything I want it to do, except for one small detail that I cannot deal with - it adds an empty line at the beginning of textbox, that is:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remvoe it at the beginning

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
    InitializeComponent();                
    logTextBox.Document.Blocks.Remove(logTextBox.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock);
 }
```